# Looping a vba code so it works an many worksheets in a workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for some help in having a specific code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, 
    Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B1:B10")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        If ActiveCell.Value = ChrW(&H2713) Then
            ActiveCell.ClearContents
        Else
            ActiveCell.Value = ChrW(&H2713)
        End If
        Cancel = True
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

so that it works on many sheets in a workbook.  I have scoured the internet and found a code or two for looping a code, but I'm having trouble with how the code is supposed to look within the looping code.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.   Thank you!!

I tried changing the Private Sub line to :
Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Sh As Object, _
ByVal Target As Range, ByVal Cancel As Boolean) but received a Complie error: Procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having the same name.
I'm very sorry, but I am very new to VBA and need help on how to word the code .....

Comment: You have no loop in this code block. Aside from that it is inside a worksheet event sub, you need to use a workbook event sub in the workbooks code behind to apply to multiple sheets. something like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.sheetbeforedoubleclick)

Comment: You just need to put that code in each worksheet you want it to run in or if you want it to run under all sheets, add it to "ThisWorkbook"

Comment: What does *many sheets* mean? Do you have an exceptions list i.e. a few worksheets that will not be included?

Answer (score 0):

### `Workbook_SheetBeforeDoubleClick` (in `ThisWorkbook`)

- Adjust the values in the `Exceptions` array.
- Assuming that *many worksheets* means **all, except a few** whose names will be in the `Exceptions` array.

**Workbook Module: `ThisWorkbook`**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Sh As Object, _
                                            ByVal Target As Range, _
                                            Cancel As Boolean)
    
    On Error GoTo clearError
    
    Dim Exceptions As Variant
    Exceptions = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")
    If UBound(Exceptions) >= LBound(Exceptions) Then
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(Sh.Name, Exceptions, 0)) Then
            'Debug.Print "Is in Exceptions."
            GoTo ProcExit
        End If
    End If
    
    If Intersect(Target, Sh.Range("B1:B10")) Is Nothing Then
        'Debug.Print "Not in Exceptions, but out of bounds."
        GoTo ProcExit
    End If
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    If ActiveCell.Value = ChrW(&H2713) Then
        ActiveCell.ClearContents
    Else
        ActiveCell.Value = ChrW(&H2713)
    End If
    Cancel = True
    
CleanExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

ProcExit:
    Exit Sub

clearError:
    Debug.Print "Run-time Error '" & Err.Number & "': " & Err.Description
    On Error GoTo 0
    GoTo CleanExit

End Sub
```